# How to add a Toolbar in NavigationView and adjust its position

Tags: android, android-support-library, navigationview

I wanted to add a toolbar in NavigationView of DrawerLayout and when i did so by using the `<include>` tag in the NavigationView to feed it another layout file having a toolbar, it adds it but the toolbar gets partially hidden by the status bar. The other thing is that; when I see it in Android Studio, it shows me the desired output...this problem happens when I run the app. Here are the screenshots if incase anyone wants to see what i meant.[image: Design in Android Studio][image]

And also last thing is that, when I use `android:layout_marginTop` to push it downwards a little bit, it pushes it further in other phones having a smaller screen size.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Toolbar should not be in NavigationView.

Try it:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<RelativeLayout>

<Toolbar/>

</RelativeLayout>

<NavigationView/>
</DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but as you can seen on the ScreenShots i've posted, i have a Toolbar in the DrawerLayout. What i needed is another toolbar in the NavigationView. And of course, it's possible to have one in the NavigationView... what bothered me is the fact that it's partially hidden by the title bar.